# Java NIO: Why the method names "read" "write" sounds the opposite?

Tags: java, nio, naming

I am new to Java NIO and I am not an English native speaker.

When I read the method call about reading and writing buffer, I always get confused.  It sounds the opposite to me.

For example,

```
fileChannel.read(buffer)
```

According to [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) javadoc, it means

> *Reads* a sequence of bytes from this channel *into* the given buffers

I wonder why it does not call "write" instead.

In English, "write into" and "read from" sounds a more natural pairs than "write from" and "read into".  Also in code reading too

```
fileChannel.write(buffer)
```

> FileChannel *writes* a sequence of bytes *into* the given buffers

This clearly states what the actor is going to do.

Now I need to read everything opposite in order to get thing right...

Maybe they call them like that because of historical reason how they call them in IO package?  Or maybe I am missing something obvious?  Hope I could have your advice how to interpret them correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Naturally, I think `read()` says "read from", whether that writes into some other object is an implementation detail. Similar for `write()`. Something is written to the parameter

Comment: I guess it could be called `readTo` or something. If it was called `write` it would be really confusing. What would `ReadableByteChannel` be called then?

Comment: They don't sound opposite to me. The real question is why they sound opposite *to you*, and only you can answer that. Possibly a native language issue?

Comment: Same reason people "read a book" rather than "write a book to their head".

Comment: "People read a book", I will interpret it as "People read content from a book".   The same reason, "FileChannel read buffer", I tend to interpret it as "FileChannel read content from buffer", but here it means "FileChannel read content into buffer".

Comment: Thanks @Bubletan, I also agree `readTo` would be a better name when an object is provided.

Comment: @Gerry a FileChannel doesn’t read buffers, it reads files. Just like people read books.

Comment: "People read book" could be written as `people.read(book)`.  But `fileChannel.read(buffer)` does not mean the same here.

Comment: As an object is provided to write into, I think the emphasis should put on the "write" action while the "read" part could be implied.   `fileChannel.write(buffer)` are preferred while `fileChannel.readTo(buffer)` is also good.  But anyway thanks everyone for the comment.   I am about to close the thread.

Answer (score 5):

When you have `object.verb(…)`, the verb is generally being performed on the object, so if you want to read the `fileChannel`, you should have `fileChannel.read(…)`.

Answer (score 1):

In any data transfer, there's always a **source** from which data is **read**, and a **destination** to which the data is **written**.  Perhaps because files are rather more permanent than memory buffer contents, it's just always been the convention to name transfer operations involving a file and a memory buffer with respect to the **role of the file** rather than that of the buffer.  So when the **file is the source** and the buffer the destination, it's a "read" and when the **file is the destination** and the buffer the source, it's a "write".

Comment: Thanks @Kevin.  Your explanation is convincing, in particular regarding who is more important and has more emphasis on the role of data transfer.